# Formula works in excel and not in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, google-spreadsheets

The following formula works in Excel but not in Google Spreadsheet:

=INDEX(Sheet1!B1:P1,MATCH(MAXA(Sheet1!B11:P11), Sheet1!B11:P11,0))

Would there be alternatives?

Thanks,

Bing

Comment: What does it do in Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Its a formula that returns the column name based on highest count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!B1:P1,1,MATCH(MAXA(Sheet1!B11:P11), Sheet1!B11:P11,0))
```

Seems that Google Spreadsheet prefers to have the row AND the column indicator in the Index() formula, although the help says they're optional.

Looks like Excel is more robust.

Comment: That works! I agree with you. It says optional. Thank you so much